# How to set production quotas when using SpaceChem's puzzle creator?

Tags: spacechem

In ResearchNet it seems that you can select what molecules or atoms are required at the outputs for an assignment.  But I can't find any place to set the quota numbers.  It seems every "Research Assignment" has a quota of 10, and every "Production Assignment" picks a quota of 40.

Can this number be changed, to various values as in the actual puzzles in the game?  If so, where is the setting?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change these values.

What you probably already know or have seen:

For production, you can only change the quota on the number of reactors that are allowed, and the type of reactors.

For research, you can only select the number of reactor components